# Multiple hypothesis Testing -- sample subsets

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a dataset of ads from two groups of advertisers. Each ad has a delivery parameter that gives you the fraction of the ad that went to the 50 states of the U.S. (The fractions add up to 1). I want to compare which advertiser had the dominant delivery fraction in different states. I am comparing the fractions at the state level. So, I am running 50 t tests. Each t test is run on a subset of my dataset. Each subset is non-overlapping and involved only in 1 test. Should I be applying the correction for multiple hypothesis testing in this case?